# Oracle SQL - Mapping attributes from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables T1 and T2.

T1 -> Contains the main data

T2 -> Configuration table

T1:

```
FILE | ATTRB1 | ATTRB2 | ATTRB3 | ATTRB4 |
  F1 |    0   |    2   |    4   |    6   |
  F1 |    1   |    3   |    5   |    7   |
  F2 |    7   |    8   |    9   |    0   |
  F2 |    1   |    2   |    3   |    4   |
  F3 |    0   |    2   |    0   |    4   |
  F3 |    1   |    0   |    3   |    0   |
  F4 |    3   |    6   |    9   |    0   |
  F4 |    4   |    8   |    1   |    2   |
```

T2:

```
ATTRB_ID | ATTRB_NAME |   COLUMN  | TABLE_REF |
    1    |    WORDS   |   ATTRB1  |     T1    |
    2    |    CHARS   |   ATTRB2  |     T1    |
    3    |    MATCH   |   ATTRB3  |     T1    |
    4    |    SPACES  |   ATTRB4  |     T1    |
```

Note: Mapping between T1 and T2 is using COLUMN attribute and TABLE_REF. If TABLE_REF is T1 then the records in it refer to T1.

Result Table:

```
FILE |  WORDS |  CHARS |  MATCH | SPACES |
  F1 |    0   |    2   |    4   |    6   |
  F1 |    1   |    3   |    5   |    7   |
  F2 |    7   |    8   |    9   |    0   |
  F2 |    1   |    2   |    3   |    4   |
  F3 |    0   |    2   |    0   |    4   |
  F3 |    1   |    0   |    3   |    0   |
  F4 |    3   |    6   |    9   |    0   |
  F4 |    4   |    8   |    1   |    2   |
```

How can we achieve the above result using oracle SQL?

Any help on this topic is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you will need some dynamic SQL to do this.

Comment: the first line in the result table, are those rows i.e part of the result set or are those columns for the  result table?

Comment: @Dawn, They are columns for the result. Those column names are taken from the T2 table's rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpivot data from `T1`, join with `T2`, pivot again:

```
select *
  from (
    select rn, file_, val, attrb_name
      from (select * from (select rownum rn, t1.* from t1) 
                           unpivot (val for attr in (ATTRB1, ATTRB2, ATTRB3, ATTRB4))) t1
      left join t2 on t2.col = t1.attr)
  pivot (max(val) for attrb_name in ('WORDS', 'CHARS', 'MATCH', 'SPACES'))
  order by rn
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a051506dd8ccee5b0451cd5e6f2a679)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that returns a cursor

```
create or replace function query2 (p_table varchar2) 
   return sys_refcursor 
is 
   rf_cur   sys_refcursor; 
   sql_stm varchar2(4000); 
begin 

  select 'SELECT ' || listagg('"'||column_name||'"' || nvl2(attrb_name,' as "'||attrb_name||'"',''),',') within group (order by column_id) ||' FROM '||p_table  into sql_stm 
  from user_tab_columns  
  left join t2 on column_name = "COLUMN" 
  where table_name = p_table; 
 dbms_output.put_line(sql_stm);
   open rf_cur for sql_stm; 
   return rf_cur; 
end query2;
```

Usage: `select query2('T1') from dual;`